# Unusable RSA keys generated on iphone

Tags: objective-c, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to generate RSA keypair using standard objective-c function: SecKeyGeneratePair.

All is ok, I can export this key to some file, but this key is unusable. When I import to C# application, i receive "bad data" errors.

If I look deeper in this key (f.eg. using http://lapo.it/asn1js/), I can see that prime number "P" is bigger, than in any key generated using different tool. This number has 1025 bits, instead no more than 1024...

Generated key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAw7plSEd4ZCK8O8n+z4wePDhR4VaKhl1ynOy4YJNTbpbBjSbV
sbr+wU8GqnkTj/NSjw0ypRWxognEZkt/SkLDrZ3dCgeLyuLntEMAZ2azWyrnsJWy
jBYhJ3nh3ZwW9K/0gQa5qOaWjstFuCLSHYiQktgFfjx4JpLCgpKkhEr8xBhnEJWn
kUwGbxRdWpeWcIiz7DFmqRKQ1cf+8WlkAuxVAcslhxDZaC/+OLCkrlFpMjRt2Dks
FYsaqBmKfeU8Oq00/m5ZBUwoKR9S1l/KTxtSQgvMAENs7XtwA9+LGZR6RXc1/7hk
GYL38ATmSA5YLXRTxg98n0prvgYj23nK5SYIyQIDAQABAoIBAFIRGpyG0xTxd4l+
NagicR8A4lwgZC7YidEAdIKR416wOXGMwfcml+DH2Nyrraci+A/hEcYkZXmyrLXT
nAiwG8n1MhQde+DS6SItIcM5TaTBRapF6jpQoRAjS7AW3Y01Jcjf4ALQxHoVAyOk
/gLCGxRnHU6D3kEWMhZ7lB2gL4Gscxe/G01piioPZfuzBGAUS+btsfGnPJdtNQJz
M9cX3FR00r4aBTYUndL90orQClkNrxqrGRCjZ3ThG+mAgUPx7X0FZvG6eUATIjFl
AhQfOSeLFRJXFj8VqffffbDDcW6yWP1png5r3ltfo4F/VZJ1pZIyruts5+RQq7YT
XTvyCs0CgYEBpZa8d0KChXv1fEaVjDA+db/s/5bDdb46bq5vTCNCNE772iN31dkI
/PGXisSgrTmyrwugZ1T5THPmMDDlBPu8JSACPlzgg31PWvQ4S429dsd/kbrxMq5u
rZQ2gRDjGVg32CJErV+UzHJ97g1HST4IkSTaIlqTHTLzfRTkairFbIcCgYB22fF0
+2PSPyK3ktRX5psgVyAgYt+1rc5+T/++2GQyRBEL4ZU86KeduBaZeUaOVGuSPu7C
doBYlYy3OWesp1/fzDXKfaCT/9TnRIgSY1XaJg6Qnma6HnGnTWjfjLiM3rdfImB/
2Bsyeak5+QjbqSf05sLFgZlcj+S2iCLjW2MELwKBgQC8YRJtp8ZypuUWVuPT9Gq0
asIXouJL5mhttHv+5XJbtT9MRbTyVTxy6fDxDNNPFA0HsoZGJe4Pf2pH9lEfXOzB
GgBmpVGc741Z8u6EtB0IyjPyhjnoj5Dc9vEz0rvnQ0gQx58waRkwEai7iitkStfB
I1plJ1u9HFs4dPFrjxkQWQKBgEHGkFj7n90F0ALkodwb5hJZ5Y/G6KQ1kqhZQeKv
A5TGEuEOcXeKEum4rdk2QxQWKIqBhcXdq15bNctZW8UzxF2pOMPeDvaZiYyMYvo6
O5NFqJ3k7Flo6+F5d+bwjFp6D+X4sotOYI7owf0xk/NthI2HAJgqB2QwxpU2doh5
VS1FAoGBAWw6lShxyuMwFIzD6EmOnX+HjYLlDTeVNy7pv/Vm7DtSIPsY2dg/iqU/
uCXsjQf5U1chYeE3hFUbPAGGbTxIL7/m6Y+ZjoKBywjSB9favG9BfQmjpRBBjmPO
cdPbTs9imzSaavoTPinJ/PeiqrfrW0tPKA049qP/X8xQrQe2erKp
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Are there any other ways to generate this key?

-------EDIT--------------------

I generated new key:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

```
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAvMkeQSIYKof9baN+ZMvtlhkcJdiQvyoVJwEST285/9h+CB4c
2/6gCp9/OvsWAADqLGA9R/XxUjezkC28efoLguiSmO8b+1BLB+05eE8V7dwJT2zG
lHrGzjcN+ZhqO3uHRhVcckUWXygb+YZl02mtSidXr9PmlI53pECJTgmM6wZOu1Df
CU1nCyLwN9zomkTAfkp7UX2pMJBARVod73FFILaRxJXNX6/61jMrVuTlGXLshDgr
BsfgHd9D4rnfMZtIn7DTUSit+Za0zmvJDKKtXSNYdGO82UnSUv+IlyzVcCNH+uPe
nSEPMqrHi83fi/aX/SwwdD+yA+jv4n2cfm75zwIDAQABAoIBAGO9mkdtPPlTidig
NYoJmAfiUlXIeokVMcG+ti7TpAABIG0ng7XTbDjQlcbSm4f6873oRtg7H3mBxlPZ
ZifHrMdIGxPD2LPJcyrH8cIXfo2B4EVfQfd2eoy+15pUJWQx2oFzjbktuSkjJsyJ
bkjpH037RT+3I66/KoTUN/bL4vDT9kejp4+11Cs5moP9Li/uXFsPJqfYTcQx19sc
w6+m9LU3WVW/7AJ3bPJvW/uwF/SE08YjPQ32vkDVwTsKCmrUaZrfUhCxlo0QCjC4
vVgVzVgs7fv1JVIgtDfp+1SuuEcHGx4j/tewoP3GX3LAA6lQYfz13LLkD0lO58Qg
MzCs95ECgYEBn5fAEfZ2YtKpOGNxyA5lIp/mG4Va2xEUY9xZ2d73g3gtN2pP8rNe
O5yjbO9eLKaJ17aU/HuwyCEkyIic7d6XfJmJEiiOXIXLSxXrh7C0d1VyWdoPfrxz
3Yk6fuBOIah2v/QalPXNPeMOE6AkzpnZmdNjmmmzdxAvAbRWdqU9uBkCgYB0SiNU
1ngVtpaN/jGp3XTtI4SARu9XhSeeeaG/s+tEKObvkUsc3UDyJRn2UjPsXnCBgLcg
yFMetCGv76UGKuJYdiUstjaOS8iym4xuklh5hKHUTE3y3fBmc4fH7e+1Jk7VGhjm
q/eQWUPtaVi16DpSE7FffmfeI4JSxMYKDL0eJwKBgQGcd2v1Z/tPUW0JvgjrWP4f
QzuKDOyDh4wJIGU8ywI0xU17NlRquILJ/0hjkZ6SCie8pEVx4QEvX1W2gX/exZDr
5SYZk47XXSLLPtIoNcSmu3NmofnG+xqzwMMBsXVaCmzxTkAjn2E4DuWlrMdbFW7W
MOsmEcpAXRuKQYWe85kx4QKBgASbOzMNG8ygYu5U91qnLw6FraX3KVvqJlucrc+O
LO+SPzOWKceG7B+rYI/lSbE/PG2kz5w40zIQKJVzhLHt2PFwHKDcxuR0FAsfJjzr
Bx4pJs/mBeBs8izcvrAouKoQTmcalYntnezV3F73IVBzVnwR06DYvPyLo4nryXx0
bLlZAoGBATNu+VCOU+y5tXNN8rwGBZO+fjAidgVXwo24DxFUdXIWZUT7DvXz+1HH
B900fBkQWXGPaDQhmqtz5eJUOlgUIlTqRo7tWivQcioq8xdvk3LA81GhGxeDpSAU
W59OGqm3ApaKnZla0B3nQ9AxdAzqf5x5SOhL9PqBbVuTRm49BIj8
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here is iPhone exported public key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvMkeQSIYKof9baN+ZMvt
lhkcJdiQvyoVJwEST285/9h+CB4c2/6gCp9/OvsWAADqLGA9R/XxUjezkC28efoL
guiSmO8b+1BLB+05eE8V7dwJT2zGlHrGzjcN+ZhqO3uHRhVcckUWXygb+YZl02mt
SidXr9PmlI53pECJTgmM6wZOu1DfCU1nCyLwN9zomkTAfkp7UX2pMJBARVod73FF
ILaRxJXNX6/61jMrVuTlGXLshDgrBsfgHd9D4rnfMZtIn7DTUSit+Za0zmvJDKKt
XSNYdGO82UnSUv+IlyzVcCNH+uPenSEPMqrHi83fi/aX/SwwdD+yA+jv4n2cfm75
zwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And here C# exported publi key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBITANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ4AMIIBCQKCAQC8yR5BIhgqh/1to35ky+2W
GRwl2JC/KhUnARJPbzn/2H4IHhzb/qAKn386+xYAAOosYD1H9fFSN7OQLbx5+guC
6JKY7xv7UEsH7Tl4TxXt3AlPbMaUesbONw35mGo7e4dGFVxyRRZfKBv5hmXTaa1K
J1ev0+aUjnekQIlOCYzrBk67UN8JTWcLIvA33OiaRMB+SntRfakwkEBFWh3vcUUg
tpHElc1fr/rWMytW5OUZcuyEOCsGx+Ad30Piud8xm0ifsNNRKK35lrTOa8kMoq1d
I1h0Y7zZSdJS/4iXLNVwI0f6496dIQ8yqseLzd+L9pf9LDB0P7ID6O/ifZx+bvnP
AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To import key to C# i use BouncyCastle library:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\pawel_000\\Documents\\Tmp\\mBankFasada\\klucze4\\private2048.pem"));
        RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters bckey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject()).Private;
        RSAParameters key = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(bckey);
```

In iPhone i signed following string: 607767767

And sign result is (in base64, hash: SHA512):

```
SQ3FqzCko8t3oL14czjjEkRgRVO4Z8F5135MFvJNKcN6w/JPYLxtWQicHQi5N
p72uNAh4Xy3g/EVukme1bZScE4prng0huZY/aWv2jUUhgRtNYrExlY6ScHkh+
asUgj8jThGB2CPQq1qSOroCcFeRAoGk7f4JPZnuZkvvgnTIPu72OrsuGhWH
AE5SFF+Z0MGbtdKM1mhK6PMeAEHBm2Iu0axN3G9IWoLF613dzHPPK6wrkkd8
8mGqrzlw/Pwo6d9IzSdHWnteGBUaOvx2EH5MQiMhJtiAnbhBtPLrmYn2bxP9
bsg3ymYW4gdmOtMgLRaheoaxBfgZ6Hrl5BAtwO7BA==
```

I can prepare public key for C# (modulus and exponent are ok), but verification failes..

Comment: Note that you may want to convert your private key into a PKCS#12 store including a certificate. That's one key format that C# should be able to read without issue (depending on the API of course).

Comment: I'll try, but as all parameters in this key are in right place after C# import, I do not think, that there is any import issue..

Comment: As the key seems correct, maybe you could show how you import/use the key in C#...

Answer (score 0):

That's a 2048 bit key, which includes the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem) parameters. These parameters can be used to speed up signature generation and decryption. There seems nothing wrong with the PKCS#1 (+PEM) encoding of that key, but the question is if the receiving application is actually expecting that format.

Note that the CRT parameters are expected to be about half the size of the private key, and are encoded at the end of the private key.

Following is the `openssl asn1parse` output of the given private key, first is the version integer (0), then the modulus, the public exponent, the private exponent and then the CRT parameters.

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1187 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim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
  268:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
  273:d=1  hl=4 l= 256 prim: INTEGER           :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
  533:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim: INTEGER           :01A596BC774282857BF57C46958C303E75BFECFF96C375BE3A6EAE6F4C2342344EFBDA2377D5D908FCF1978AC4A0AD39B2AF0BA06754F94C73E63030E504FBBC2520023E5CE0837D4F5AF4384B8DBD76C77F91BAF132AE6EAD94368110E3195837D82244AD5F94CC727DEE0D47493E089124DA225A931D32F37D14E46A2AC56C87
  665:d=1  hl=3 l= 128 prim: INTEGER           :76D9F174FB63D23F22B792D457E69B2057202062DFB5ADCE7E4FFFBED8643244110BE1953CE8A79DB8169979468E546B923EEEC2768058958CB73967ACA75FDFCC35CA7DA093FFD4E74488126355DA260E909E66BA1E71A74D68DF8CB88CDEB75F22607FD81B3279A939F908DBA927F4E6C2C581995C8FE4B68822E35B63042F
  796:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim: INTEGER           :BC61126DA7C672A6E51656E3D3F46AB46AC217A2E24BE6686DB47BFEE5725BB53F4C45B4F2553C72E9F0F10CD34F140D07B2864625EE0F7F6A47F6511F5CECC11A0066A5519CEF8D59F2EE84B41D08CA33F28639E88F90DCF6F133D2BBE7434810C79F3069193011A8BB8A2B644AD7C1235A65275BBD1C5B3874F16B8F191059
  928:d=1  hl=3 l= 128 prim: INTEGER           :41C69058FB9FDD05D002E4A1DC1BE61259E58FC6E8A43592A85941E2AF0394C612E10E71778A12E9B8ADD936431416288A8185C5DDAB5E5B35CB595BC533C45DA938C3DE0EF699898C8C62FA3A3B9345A89DE4EC5968EBE17977E6F08C5A7A0FE5F8B28B4E608EE8C1FD3193F36D848D8700982A076430C69536768879552D45
 1059:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim: INTEGER           :016C3A952871CAE330148CC3E8498E9D7F878D82E50D3795372EE9BFF566EC3B5220FB18D9D83F8AA53FB825EC8D07F953572161E13784551B3C01866D3C482FBFE6E98F998E8281CB08D207D7DABC6F417D09A3A510418E63CE71D3DB4ECF629B349A6AFA133E29C9FCF7A2AAB7EB5B4B4F280D38F6A3FF5FCC50AD07B67AB2A9
```

Note that the values within the ASN.1 DER encoding may start with `00` adding an extra byte. That is because ASN.1 INTEGER values are *signed*. So if the modulus would not start with `00` it would represent a negative integer.

Comment: It looks like, that there is rather "01" extra, than "00" :) Is this proper? XCA (that uses OpenSSL libraries) imports/exports this key without problem, but any key generated by XCA does not have this extra bytes, "01" at the beginning of any prime...

Comment: That's not a problem, as long as the values are about half of the key size. If they are not you may be in trouble as these parameters do determine the security of the key. If they are equal in value then alarm bells should be ringing :)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable do solve problem, but part of it was just for test purposes. exporting private key generated on iphone should not be desired application feature :)

Despide this still doesn't work, I am now able to sign data using key generated on iphone, and properly verify it in c#

All was about padding while using SHA512 hash, it should be:

```
#define kTypeOfSigPadding   kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA512 
#define kDigestLength   CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
```

...

```
sanityCheck = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey,
                            kTypeOfSigPadding,
                            (const uint8_t *)[shaHash bytes],
                            kDigestLength,
                            (uint8_t *)signedHashBytes,
                            &signedHashBytesSize);
```

Public key is imported to .NET manually, reading modulus and exponent from ASN1.